# Access rights to submodules under github

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-submodules

I want a github project *projectA* which uses a submodule *projectSub*. I further want users to be able to clone the project recursively, automatically getting both *projectA* and *projectSub*.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but as I understand it, cloning `https://github.com/username/projectname`  implies that you will be asked for username and password before pushing, whereas cloning `git@github.com:username/projectname` will use your ssh credentials automatically.

Now, I can add the submodule thus

```
git add submodule git@github.com:username/projectSub
```

or thus

```
git add submodule https://github.com/username/projectSub
```

If I use the first method, a user *without* ssh access to the project will not be able to recursively clone *projectA*, because the `.gitmodules` file contains `git@github.com:...`.

But if I use the second method, a user *with* ssh access to the project will nevertheless be asked to provide username and password when pushing updates to *projectSub*, because the `.gitmodules` file contains `https://github.com/...`.

Is there a way to make this work for both kinds of users? (Or have I completely misunderstood how this works?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make this work for both kinds of users? (Or have I completely misunderstood how this works?)

When working with submodules, I find it easiest to treat the submodules as read-only clones.  If I need to make updates, I clone the upstream repository separately, then `git pull` the changes into the submodule.

That said, you can still make this work.  Use the `https://` URLs by default.  For people who need to push changes, they will:

```
git remote set-url --push git@github.com:username/projectSub
```

Git permits you to have separate `push` and `pull` URLs.